# How boot to terminal Ubuntu 12.04 MacbookPro

Tags: 12.04, boot, command-line, macbook

I tried to boot into terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> in my ubuntu 12.04 mbp, but it always boot into GUI.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+T doesn't boot into the terminal, just calls the gnome-terminal application.

If what you mean is you want to log in to a tty, try Ctrl+Alt+F# (where # is a value between 2 and 6) For instance, Ctrl+Alt+F6.

You can go back to the GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7.